# How to sum arrays based on the first field

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I have 3 array of hashes:

```
a = [{name: 'Identifier', value: 500}, {name: 'Identifier2', value: 50 }]
b = [{name: 'Identifier', value: 500}, {name: 'Identifier2', value: 50 }]
c = [{name: 'Identifier', value: 500}, {name: 'Identifier2', value: 50 }]
```

and I have to merge them into one, based on the `name` prop of each identifier, so the result will be:

```
d = [{name: 'Identifier', value: 1500 }, {name: 'Identifier2', value: 150}]
```

Is there a smart ruby way of doing this, or do I have to do create another hash where the keys are the identifiers, the values the values and then transform it into an array?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the order of identifiers in all arrays the same? That is `{name: 'Identifier', value: ...}` always the first element in all 3 arrays, `{name: 'Identifier2', value: ... }` always the second?

Answer (score 2):

When the values of a single key in a collection of hashes are to be totaled I usually begin by constructing a *counting hash*:

```
h = (a+b+c).each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h[g[:name]] = (h[g[:name]] || 0) + g[:value]
end
  #=> {"Identifier"=>1500, "Identifier2"=>150}
```

Note that if `h` does not have a key `g[:name]`, `h[g[:name]] #=> nil`, so:

```
h[g[:name]] = (h[g[:name]] || 0) + g[:value]
            = (nil || 0) + g[:value]
            = 0 + g[:value]
            = g[:value]
```

We may now easily obtain the desired result:

```
h.map { |(name,value)| { name: name, value: value } }
  #=> [{:name=>"Identifier", :value=>1500},
  #    {:name=>"Identifier2", :value=>150}]
```

If desired these two expressions can be chained:

```
(a+b+c).each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h[g[:name]] = (h[g[:name]] || 0) + g[:value]
end.map { |(name,value)| { name: name, value: value } }
  #=> [{:name=>"Identifier", :value=>1500},
  #    {:name=>"Identifier2", :value=>150}]
```

Sometimes you might see:

```
h[k1] = (h[k1] || 0) + g[k2]
```

written:

```
(h[k1] ||= 0) + g[k2]
```

which expands to the same thing.

Another way to calculate `h`, which I would say is more "Ruby-like", is the following.

```
h = (a+b+c).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
  h[g[:name]] += g[:value]
end
```

This creates the hash represented by the block variable `h` using the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument called the *default value*:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

All this means is that if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value, here `0`. Note that

```
h[g[:name]] += g[:value]
```

expands to:

```
h[g[:name]] = h[g[:name]] + g[:value]
```

so if `h` does not have a key `g[:name]` this reduces to:

```
h[g[:name]] = 0 + g[:value]
```

If you were wondering why `h[g[:name]]` on the left of the equality was not replaced by `0`, it is because that part of the expression employs the method [Hash#[]=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), whereas the method [Hash#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) is used on he right. `Hash::new` with a default value only concerns `Hash#[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in ruby !

Here is a solution to your problem :

```
d = (a+b+c).group_by { |e| e[:name] }.map { |f| f[1][0].merge(value: f[1].sum { |g| g[:value] }) }
```

I encourage you to check the Array Ruby doc for more information: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the order of identifiers in all arrays is the same. That is `{name: 'Identifier', value: ...}` always the first element in all 3 arrays, `{name: 'Identifier2', value: ... }` always the second, etc. In this simple case, a simple `each_with_index` is a simple and clear solution:

```
d = []

a.each_with_index do |hash, idx|
  d[idx] = {name: hash[:name], value: a[idx][:value] + b[idx][:value] + c[idx][:value] }
end

# Or a more clear version using map:

a.each_with_index do |hash, idx|
  d[idx] = {name: hash[:name], value: [a, b, c].map { |h| h[idx][:value] }.sum }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple different ways, avoiding any finicky array-indexing and the like, (also functionally, since you've added the tag):

```rb
grouped = (a + b + c).group_by { _1[:name] }
name_sums = grouped.transform_values { |hashes| hashes.map { _1[:value] }.sum }
```

```rb
name_vals = (a + b + c).map { Hash[*_1.values_at(:name, :value)] }
name_sums = name_vals.reduce { |l, r| l.merge(r) { |k, lval, rval| lval + rval } }
```

in either case, finish it off with:

```rb
name_sums.map { |name, value| { name: name, value: value } }
```